# What type of UML will best suite to represent my Project Architecture for business users

Tags: architecture, uml

I have developed 5 micro services as part of my project and i want to represent complete project architecture as UML diagram (i have to represent these microservices and their interactions) so that business users can easily understand the project. Can any one please suggest what type of UML diagram best suites my requirement.

Comment: I am afraid your question is too broad ...

Comment: You answered it yourself: component and interaction diagrams.

Comment: Why business users need to understand technical topics of the project?

Comment: @Vershov they dont need to understand technical topics, they want to see the Architecture of the project. at high level.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're wanting to represent.

Behaviour and interactions can be modelled several ways, as a starter however you could use either Sequence diagrams (a.k.a Interaction diagrams) and/or Communication Diagrams. You can use either of these at both the code level (i.e. objects talking to each other) or at the Component level (i.e. instances of components talking to each other).

To model your structures, you can use either Class Diagrams (again, if at the code or information-structure logical level) and/or Component Diagrams (at the Component level).

If you're using Components, a nice trick is to build a structural model first (a Component diagram) and then use this as a template for a behavioural model represented using a Communication diagram. You could do this at the code (object) level as well but Sequence charts tend to be more common when representing code behaviour in my experience.

I recommend this book when trying to understand how to best represent architectures to different stakeholders: https://www.viewpoints-and-perspectives.info